# HTML Table Text Alignment

Tags: html, css

```
<table>
   <tr><td>aaaaa</td></tr>
   <tr><td>aaaaaaaaaa</td></tr>
   <tr><td>aaa</td></tr> 
</table>
```

I want the text of first row and third row to be right aligned but not the second line, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the HTML that you have and use the `nth-child` selector

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {
text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: @Mr.Alien You might find more unique stuff here : http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

Comment: Definitely my preferred solution, regardless of IE difficulties.

Comment: I know this, I said unique considering the same answers given by others and different solution given by you

Comment: @Mr.Alien : oops. Sorry. And thanks for the `unique` compliment. @Sam : If you want to make it work in versions of IE < 9 try http://www.css3.info/css3-pseudo-selectors-emulation-in-internet-explorer/

Comment: This is a nice solution, but I need to support all browsers, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple.

```
 <table>
       <tr style="text-align:right;"><td>aaaaa</td></tr>
       <tr><td>aaaaaaaaaa</td></tr>
       <tr style="text-align:right;><td>aaa</td></tr> 
    </table>
```

Or use classes:

```
<table>
           <tr class="tr-right"><td>aaaaa</td></tr>
           <tr><td>aaaaaaaaaa</td></tr>
           <tr class="tr-right"><td>aaa</td></tr> 
        </table>
```

And add to css:

```
.tr-right{text-align:right;}
```

Or as mentioned, you could use the css3 selector, but this doesn't work in all browsers.

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {
text-align:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class='right'><td>aaa</td></tr>
        <tr><td>aaa</td></tr>
        <tr class='right'><td>aaa</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

.rigth{
 text-align:rigth;
}
```